# How to run javascript in Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, safari

How to run javascript in Safari browser?
Hi. I’m using Safari. I want to run javascript in browser. How can I click on the CopySelector below with Javascript?
#tads > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div.abcde.wxyz > a

I want to write a code like here: https://help.apple.com/assets/61B8D8A63A464E30E6506C04/61B8D8A93A464E30E6506C13/tr_TR/968cf5cd5f1461e99743748d450ac091.png
Thanks.

Comment: That looks like it is an Apple Shortcut automation and it just takes regular JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to write and run JavaScript code in Safari browser.

Follow the following steps:

1. **Enable Safari dev tools:** To open Safari dev tools, press `Ctrl + Alt + C` on Windows or
   `command + option + C` Mac. Or enable Safari dev commands in the menubar in Safari Settings -> Advanced -> Show features for web developer.
2. Select the console in dev tools window. Check this image. Your selected console should look like this
   :
   [image: Image showing selection of the console in dev tools window.]
3. Now Start writing the code in console

( **Note:** For Multiline code press `shift` + `enter` to change the line )

4. To run the code press `Enter`

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of browsers: `Safari -> Settings -> Advanced -> Show features for web developers`

Answer (score 0):

Enable JavaScript in Safari :

Launch Safari from your desktop or Dock.
From the main menu at the top of your screen, click Safari and then Preferences...
Click the Security icon.
In the Web content section, ensure that the Enable JavaScript check box has been checked.
Close this window.